# Showing images from path in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get an understanding of how to retrieve an images from a path stored in mysql database. I have the path as sumple images

Here's the code that I have tried so far.

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
   <!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $sql = 'Select * from images';
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Crazy man');

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $url = 'http://localhost/image_path/'. $row[image_path];
            echo "<img src='$url' height='200' width='200' />";
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code below

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $url = 'http://localhost/image_path/'. $row[image_path];
        echo "<img src='$url' height='200' width='200' />";
    }
```

I think you need to change it to something like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $url = 'image_path/'. $row[image_path];
        echo "<img src='$url' height='200' width='200' />";
    }
```

Take note that I removed the `http://localhost/`

in your `$url = 'http://localhost/image_path/'. $row[image_path];`

Whenever you try to load images the **default directory is automatically loaded** so you can just put **/image_path/blah-blah directly**.

Comment: Ok I tried both way and it didn't work, but I deleted the http:localhost part and it still didn't work. image_path is my root folder so is that needed. When I deleted the whole thing and was left with just $row[image_path] I was given a link with the name of the image. When I click the image it showed the images but I want the image to automatically show. And do I need to specify the images name and extension?

Comment: Yeah, you should specify the images name and extension.
For example.
If your picture is cary-bondoc.jpg
then your data in database should be like cary-bondoc.jpg

Comment: Ok I know this is closed but one more question what if I want to show all images in a directory not just one?

Comment: I think that code of yours will loop through all data in your database, please add more datas. Also you can refer to this site for more info about that matter http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php